# What might be the problem in my stat_ellipse fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a simple scatter plot which should include a `stat_ellipse` with `fill`.

```
ggplot(feature, aes(x=PC1,y=PC2, colour=Factor1, shape=Factor1))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.8,size=4,stroke=2)+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,1,2))+
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill=Factor1),show.legend = FALSE,alpha=0.5)+
  xlab("PC1 (19%)")+
  ylab("PC2 (12%)")
```

My issue is with my ellipse not being filled.

Also, a warning message shows:

> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill

My current plot:

[image: output]

Comment: Please post sample data or create a small mock dataframe for reproducibility if it's PHI sensitive data. df %>% head() %>% dput()

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `stat_ellipse` by default uses `geom="path"` which has no `fill` aesthetic. To achieve your desired result switch to `geom="polygon"`.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), geom = "polygon", alpha = .5)
```

[image]